# Parentheses algorithm clarification in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the below method that generates all valid opened and closed combinations of parentheses:

```
public static void getParentheses(int openParenthesis, int closeParenthesis, String string) {
    if (openParenthesis == 0 && closeParenthesis == 0) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    if (openParenthesis > closeParenthesis) {
        return;
    }

    if (openParenthesis > 0) {
        System.out.println("openParenthesis: " + openParenthesis + " / closeParenthesis: " + closeParenthesis);
        getParentheses(openParenthesis - 1, closeParenthesis, string + "(");
    }

    if (closeParenthesis > 0) {
        System.out.println("openParenthesis: " + openParenthesis + " / closeParenthesis: " + closeParenthesis);
        getParentheses(openParenthesis, closeParenthesis - 1, string + ")");
    }
}
```

And I call this method using this line:

```
getParentheses(3, 3, "");
```

The output is:

```
openParenthesis: 3 / closeParenthesis: 3
openParenthesis: 2 / closeParenthesis: 3
openParenthesis: 1 / closeParenthesis: 3
openParenthesis: 0 / closeParenthesis: 3
openParenthesis: 0 / closeParenthesis: 2
openParenthesis: 0 / closeParenthesis: 1
((()))
openParenthesis: 1 / closeParenthesis: 3 //Line8
openParenthesis: 1 / closeParenthesis: 2
openParenthesis: 0 / closeParenthesis: 2
openParenthesis: 0 / closeParenthesis: 1
(()())
```

I don't understand why at `Line8`, the `openParenthesis` has the value of `1`, since the last call of the method was with `0` and `0`? What makes it increase to `1`?

Comment: Returning and taking the other branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 3 and line 8 are from the same function invocation:
line 3 is produced by

```
if (openParenthesis > 0) {
    System.out.println("openParenthesis: " + openParenthesis + " / closeParenthesis: " + closeParenthesis);
    getParentheses(openParenthesis - 1, closeParenthesis, string + "(");
}
```

line 8 by:

```
if (closeParenthesis > 0) {
    System.out.println("openParenthesis: " + openParenthesis + " / closeParenthesis: " + closeParenthesis);
    getParentheses(openParenthesis, closeParenthesis - 1, string + ")");
}
```

after returning from recursive call.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It took me one day to understand it. Thanks!